# pip and trusted hosts

Tags: windows, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install PyTorch 1.7.0 on Windows 10 using Python 3.8.6. When simply inputing the command

```sh
pip install torch==1.7+cu101
```

I get the error :

```sh
'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1124)'))': /whl/torch_stable.html
```

When I do :

```sh
pip install --trusted-host download.pytorch.org torch==1.7.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Installation works flawlessly.

However, I would like to either :

- Ideally, handle that with the simple `pip` command and get the SSL verification to work
- handle that through the `pip` config file located in my virtual env i.e. `/path/to/my/env/pip.conf`

Unfortunately, having the `pip.conf` file like this :

```
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
               download.pytorch.org
```

does not work and seems to be ignored by `pip`

Answer (score 0):

If done globally...

C:\Users<profile>\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini
is where I see it stored for Windows Server.

If you ran this command say:

`pip config set global.trusted-host "pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.python.org"`

There is a [--user option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_config/) too.

Shame there isn't an --virtualenv option too!

More info [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/) and [virtual env here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

It  would update the aforementioned file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found the solution to this, but since I delt with this recently, that could help for future reference.
I had issues making `pip` to recognize my `pip.conf` file, so what I did was to pass the var PIP_CONFIG_FILE before running `pip`, like this:

`PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/<your pip conf path>/pip.conf pip install torch`